# How to fix error Argument of type '{ static: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'. in angular?

Tags: angular

I have the html file defined as :

```
<div class="dialogBox">
  <ng-template #callAPIDialog>
    <h2 mat-dialog-title class="dialogHeading">Scale Dimensions</h2>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Width</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter width (in ft)" #width name="width">
        <mat-hint>Enter width in number</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Height</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter height (in ft)" #height name="height">
        <mat-hint>Enter height in number</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <!-- <mat-dialog-actions> -->
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="scaleDrop(height.value,width.value)" class="buttonConfirm">CONFIRM</button>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="closeDialogBox()" class="buttonCancel">CANCEL</button>

    <!-- </mat-dialog-actions> -->
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

In my ts file i am calling it as follows:

```
@ViewChild('callAPIDialog', { static: false }) callAPIDialog: TemplateRef<any>;
  callAPI() {
............}
```

However i am getting error as follows:

Argument of type `{ static: boolean; }` is not assignable to parameter of type `{ read?: any; }`.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and `static` does not exist in type `{ read?: any; }`.

How to fix it?

Comment: What versoion of ANgular are you using?

Comment: What's your Angular version? `static` flag comes with v.8 If you are using v7, it throws this error